# In table view data was not loading and after json parsing the app was craashing

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

when i keep break points at the point mentioned in image then [image] the data was loading without crashing the application and when i didn't kept the break points and make the application to run then it was crashing can any one help me how to clear the error

[image]

my code is shown below

```
    let url = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUKEESvnvS?indent=2"
    var orderdetailsArray : [[String:AnyObject]] = []
    var itemsArray : [[String:AnyObject]] = []
    var orderid = [Any]()
    var orderdate = [Any]()
    var subTotal = [Int]()
    var shippingPrice = [Int]()
    var tax = [Int]()
    var grandTotal = [Int]()
    var shippingAddress = [AnyObject]()
    var shippingMethod = [AnyObject]()
    var billingAddress = [AnyObject]()
    var paymentMethod = [AnyObject]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.downloadJsonWithURL()
        tableDetails.delegate = self
        tableDetails.dataSource = self
        tableDetails.estimatedRowHeight = 600
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                self.orderdetailsArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Orders detail") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                if let firstDictInfo = self.orderdetailsArray.first as? [String:Any] {
                    self.itemsArray = firstDictInfo["Items detail"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return 3
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if (section == 0){
            return ""
        }
        else if (section == 1){
            return ""
        }
        else{
            return "Ordered Items"
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        if (section == 0){
            return 1
        }else if (section == 1){
            return 1
        }
        else{
            return itemsArray.count
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ordercell", for: indexPath) as! OrdersTableViewCell
            cell.orderDateLabel.text = orderdetailsArray[0]["OrderDate"] as? String
            cell.orderIdLabel.text = orderdetailsArray[0]["OrderId"]! as? String
            let totalPrice : Int = orderdetailsArray[0]["Shipping"]! as! Int
            let price = Float(totalPrice)
            cell.shippingLabel.text = "$" + "\(price)"
            let subTotalPrice : Int = orderdetailsArray[0]["SubTotal"]! as! Int
            let subtotalprice = Float(subTotalPrice)
            cell.subTotalLabel.text = "$" + "\(subtotalprice)"
            let taxPrice : Int = orderdetailsArray[0]["Tax"]! as! Int
            let taxPriceFloat = Float(taxPrice)
            cell.taxLabel.text = "$" + "\(taxPriceFloat)"
            let grandTotal : Int = self.orderdetailsArray[0]["GrandTotal"]! as! Int
            let grandPriceFloat = Float(grandTotal)
            cell.grandTotalLabel.text = "$" + "\(grandPriceFloat)"
            return cell
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 1){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingcell", for: indexPath) as! ShippingTableViewCell
            cell.shippingMethodLabel.text = orderdetailsArray[0]["ShippingMethod"] as? String
            cell.shippingAddressLabel.text = orderdetailsArray[0]["ShippingAddress"]! as? String
            cell.billingAddressLabel.text = orderdetailsArray[0]["BillingAddress"]! as? String
            cell.paymentMethodLabel.text = orderdetailsArray[0]["PayMentMethod"]! as? String
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "orderdetailscell", for: indexPath) as! OrderDetailsTableViewCell
            let array = itemsArray[indexPath.row]
            let price : Int = array["ItemPrice"] as! Int
            let grandPriceFloat = Float(price)
            cell.priceLabel.text = "$" + "\(grandPriceFloat)"
            let quant : Int = array["ItemQty"] as! Int
            cell.quantityLabel.text = "\(quant)"
            cell.productNameLabel.text = array["ItemName"] as? String
            let subTotal : Int = array["ItemSubTotal"] as! Int
            let subPriceFloat = Float(subTotal)
            cell.subTotalLabel.text = "$" + "\(subPriceFloat)"
            let grandTotal : Int = array["ItemSku"] as! Int
            cell.skuLabel.text = "\(grandTotal)"
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you print the contents of array at the time of crashing? Why are you returning static value in `numberOfRowsInSection` return `orderdetailsArray.count`

Comment: In `numberOfRowsInSection`, return instead `orderdetailsArray.count` for section 0, same for section 1.

Comment: it was returning an empty array @Priyal

Comment: how to implement just let me know i am new to swift 3 @TusharSharma

Comment: i am statically designed my two sections so i had given 1 as count @Larme

Comment: shouldn't numberOfRowsinSection should return `Or.count` for section = 3, intead of ''orderdetailsArray.count`?

Comment: i was just passing the data which i got from the orderdetailsArray to the all the sections

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what ur saying @Priyal

Comment: But when you did't fetch your data, orderedetailsArray is empty! So you can't do ordereddetailsArray[0] and explains the error message

Comment: so what should i do in my case @Larme

Comment: In `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ` you are returning static value of 1 for section = 0/1. return 1 only if `orderdetailsArray.count` is greater than 1. It won't crash in that case.

Comment: @Priyal i didn't understand what ur saying can u explain clearly ?

Comment: can u please post the answer what ur saying ?@Priyal

Comment: what is 2d arrays ? @TusharSharma

Comment: i am reloading the table data then it should load what's the reason @Larme

Comment: @VamsiKrishna posted an answer. Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to confirm if `orderDetailsArray` actually contains some value before you are accessing it. Also, you are just returning 1 for  `numberOfRowsInSection` without even checking if `orderDetailsArray` has some content. This should possibly resolve your crash:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    if (section == 0 || section == 1) {
        if orderDetailsArray.count > 0 {
               return 1
         } else {
              return 0
         }
       }
     else {
            return itemsArray.count
        }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the kind of behavior you are expecting because it will result in section Headers with no rows but, you can modify that!

Comment: bro i new to swift 3 can u help me how to implement model class ? @Priyal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149700/discussion-between-vamsi-krishna-and-priyal).

Comment: have u checked my project ? @Priyal

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Lets continue our discussion at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149700/discussion-between-vamsi-krishna-and-priyal

Comment: hw to place a collapsible label any idea ? @Priyal

Answer (score 1):

Need to **register UINib in UITableView** for use multiple custom cell in tableView.

- **How to register UINib in UITableView?**

> Just write below three line in `ViewDidLoad()`

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ShippingTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "shippingcell")
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "OrderDetailsTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "orderdetailscell")
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "OrdersTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ordercell")
```